# jQuery .data() vs HTML5 data-XXX performance

Tags: jquery, performance

I found this test http://jsbin.com/ekofa/2 that shows that HTML5 data-XXX is faster then jQuery `.data()`. I am starting a project that require lots of small data pieces placed on HTML elements where performance is crucial. Should I use `.data()` or HTML5 data-XXX? Is that test relevant and accurate?

Comment: I think the numbers speak for themselves.

Comment: Indeed but I always thought that .data() being stored in cache is faster then accessing the DOM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends where you're coming from I suppose, but for storing *simple* properties, `data-XXX` will be faster just because of how [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) work.

For example when you do this to get data:

```
var thing = $('#myelement').data('thing')
```

What you're actually doing is this:

```
var thing = $.cache[$('#myelement')[0][$.expando]]['thing'];
```

This is longer than fetching an attribute directly, like this:

```
$('#myelement').attr('thing')
```

So with data you're actually getting the `$.expando` attribute *just* to get the ID *then* going to `$.cache` to get the object, this extra step means it will be consistently slower.

Then again, `data-xxx` attributes weren't meant for storing event handlers or other really complex objects that you're actively manipulating...so they aren't a 1:1 in their application so a direct comparison may not be fair.  Though they're used for the same things in many cases, they also have *different* applications that aren't common to both...so keep that in mind when picking what to use.  This is usually true of any 2 *mostly* common technologies IMO.

Comment: I need this to store simple strings like "243px", "#333"... Not complex objects

Comment: @Mircea - Then I personally would use data attributes if you have a consistent set of properties to store :)

Comment: @NickCraver - i asked this same question recently [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266663/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-data-attribute-over-data-in-jquery/ - hadn't found this question] - and found http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/9. So confused as to whether $.data is now better ? As this test seems to show it is ?

Comment: @Tim - Yes `$.data` is the fastest (especially in 1.6.2+), because `.attr()` checks quite  few sources first, where as `$.data` is going directly to `$.cache[elem[$.expando]]['key']`, and that direct property access with no additional checks is much speedier.