# What is the advantage of using 'data-attribute' over $.data in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I was wondering what the advantage is of using data assignment to the DOM vs. NOT to the DOM

i.e. Assume we have said HTML

```
<a id="foo" href="#">foo!</a>

//Set attr data-me so it's <a id="foo" data-me="yay" href="#">foo!</a>
$('#foo').attr('data-me', 'yay');

//Retrieve the data 'yay'
$('#foo').data('data-me');
```

Over and above direct assignment:

```
var myInput = $('#foo');    

//Add some data
$.data(myInput, 'data-me', 'yay');

//Retrieve the data 'yay'
$.data(myInput, 'data-me');
```

My understanding is that the later is `MUCH` faster and therefore I can't see the sense in adding `data-someAttr` all over the DOM when it's not required ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .data() vs HTML5 data-XXX performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476497/jquery-data-vs-html5-data-xxx-performance)

Comment: @Shef - thanks hadn't seen that - however http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/2 - seems to disagree with the conclusion stated in that question ?

Comment: Yes, of course using the low level method is going to be faster.

Comment: @shef - can provide an answer as to why ? :) since @NickCraver suggests that `.attr` is faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They serve different purposes. Yes, it seems like they can be used to achieve the same thing, but under the hood there are differences.

1. While you can save [simple values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Values) in attributes, you can not save DOM nodes, because [you will create](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/UTyTf/) [memory leaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks). Neither can you save objects, arrays, functions, etc...
2. `$.attr()` might be faster than `$('selector').data()`, but it is not faster than the low-level method `jQuery.data()`. The first data method has much more overhead than the second, however the second one does not carry all the functionality of the first one. For example, [it does not get the data out of the `data-` attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/sMwcu/).

Thus, I think it's best to use `data-` attributes at load time, so you can extract the data with `$('selector').attr()`, and handle the application state with `$.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a guru, that' s for sure... but it appears to me that two obvious differences are the time/environment when the 'data' is set, and the structure(type) of data that will be stored/accessed.

Concider this scenario:

```
<a id="foo" data-me="some string data" href="#">foo!</a
```

This pice of html was maybe generated on the server side. If so,only the server side  needs to know about the 'data-me' value origin. One limitation is that the attribute must be a string , or a string representation of an object (JSON)

```
var customData = 
{
    date:new Date(),
    otherProp:'some value',
    someFunc: function(a,b)
    {
        // function dody
    }
};
$('#foo').attr('data-me', customData)
```

From the javascript(medium), at a certain moment, triggered by a certain event(time), you can use jQuery  to bind a dom element to a given object (not necessarily a string)

So the latter way ($('#foo').attr('data-me', customData)), removes the 'only string' limitation and allows you to bind to a dom element any kind of js object , even functions.

Comment: thanks for response. I'm mainly manipulating client side and was more interesting in the differences between `$.cache` and `$.attr` etc ?